# CSS: Image Centering [issue]

Tags: css, wordpress

http://alexandermasters.com/flora/2015/10/05/corey-boyce/

Trying to horizontally center the image within its respective container.

Can't seem to isolate the correct element with which to apply

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Have progressively worked my way through the code starting from the image and moving up to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code

```
.gallery-item {float:none; margin:0 auto; text-align:center}
```

1. targeting the IMG tag would not work because it is nested in another element, so you have to center the parent of the img.
2. when there is a float, margin:auto will not work properly

Comment: No luck :( Even pulled up the dev/inspector window in chrome and disabled the other float (rather than trying to override it).

Comment: I have revised my code (added text-align center) should work now, please check

Comment: Still no luck, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about IE9 compatibility, you can easily achieve this by applying `display: flex` to the parent `<dt>` element.

Check out Chris Coyier's [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you haven't already read up on this beautiful member of CSS3. I also recommend this [article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/09/modern-web-layout-with-flexbox/) by Paddi McDonnell.

Flexbox underwent some [prefixing inconsistencies](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/03/harnessing-flexbox-for-todays-web-apps/#browser-support), so it would be wise to have a fallback style if those users are important to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}
.gallery dl {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

(also clear your browser cache)